# Check if JavaFX platform is exiting

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, javafx-8

I use a background-thread that should not stop immediately when JavaFX stops (as it does when no stage is open anymore as configured with `setImplicitExit`), so I do not use `setDaemon` for this one. But how can I check if JavaFX is shutting down? (This thread should just finish some things and stop itself)

I know I could put an `setOnCloseRequest` to all stages, but I'd prefer not doing that.

`Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook()` does not work in this case as the machine does not go down as long as this thread is running).

Comment: I think you can use the Application's `stop()` method.

Answer (score 3):

Override `Application.stop()` and set a flag. Your thread will need to periodically check that flag.

SSCCE:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ExitThreadGracefullyOnExit extends Application {

    AtomicBoolean shutdownRequested = new AtomicBoolean();

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        Label countLabel = new Label();

        Thread thread = new Thread(() -> {
            try {
                int count = 0 ;
                while (! shutdownRequested.get()) {
                    count++ ;
                    final String message = "Count = "+count ;
                    Platform.runLater(() -> countLabel.setText(message));
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                }
                System.out.println("Shutdown... closing resources");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Almost done...");
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println("Exiting thread");
            } catch (InterruptedException exc) {
                System.err.println("Unexpected Interruption");
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(10, countLabel);
        root.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        thread.start();

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 350, 100);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        shutdownRequested.set(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```